# Getting undefined from onSubmit value

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't retrieve the form value it somehow keeps giving me undefined what am I doing wrong?

My HTML:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" #studentUploadForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(studentUploadForm)">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Examen:</label>

    <div class="form-group">
      <select [(ngModel)]="examen_id" name="examenId" class="form-control">
        <option [ngValue]="examen.id" *ngFor="let examen of examensStudent">{{examen.naam}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <label for="exampleInputFile">Bestand:</label>

    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Upload hier de examen die je wilt inleveren.</small>

    <button type="submit" class="pxl-knop">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

My TS:

```
export class StudentUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() examensStudent: Examen[] = [];
  examen_id = 1;

  constructor(private serv: ExamService) { }

  onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form.examen_id); //This is returning undefined
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serv.getExams().subscribe(data => this.examensStudent = data);
  }

}
```

Comment: your ngModel is incorrect - remember "banana in a box" for the order. i.e. [(ngModel)]="examen_id" Also where's the onSubmit() function call?

Comment: Ah thanks I like the rule of thumb. I also added the <form> in which I had the onSubmit() which I accidently left out in the question apologies. But it still gives me undefined.

Comment: Also the `[ngValue]="examen_id"` was meant to be `[ngValue]="examen.id"`. When I inspect the source code it does show me that the `ng-reflect-ng-value` does indeed have the numbers. But the console.log just returns undefined.

Comment: `FormGroup` does not have a property `examen_id`, so`undefined` is the expected result. Try `console.log(this.examen_id);`

Comment: Thanks those two fixed the problem! `form.value.examen_id` also worked.

Comment: @SinanSamet cool. glad you figured it out